# Convert string to array (not how you think)

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

I have an ajax function that returns a string that looks something like this: `"[{property1: value1}, {property1: value1}]"`. I need this to be an array. How can I change that from a string to an array?
I know I could append a script tag with that in it to my head, but it I doubt that doing so would be good practice or the most efficient way.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is returning that and why? Can you return JSON instead?

Comment: Perhaps it is JSON already and you are redacting it too much. Try `JSON.parse(response)`

Comment: In PHP, I query a database. I format the result to be the array that I need. What would the JSON look like?

Comment: You want to be outputting JSON in PHP too with `json_encode`. Building your own strings is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @JamesMcDowell JSON looks just like what you've given except the keys (`property1` in this case) must be surrounded with quotes (`"property1"`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method. This will convert your string to a valid JS object.

```
JSON.parse('[{"property1": "value1"}, {"property1": "value1"}]');
```

You also do the reverse using the [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) method that will convert an object to it's String representation.

Make sure that your JSON output follows the JSON standards.
For example all keys and string values must be double quoted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, it's not the best but...

```
var str = "[{property1: 'value1'} , {property1: 'value2'}]";
var array = str.replace("[","").replace("]","").split(",");
```

the split will create an array and you can access the items by the index. For example array[0] = "{property1: 'value1'}"

This helped?

Comment: Thank you, but I was looking to convert the individual elements to objects too. JSON.parse works better.